# Multivariate analysis for subjective decision making

Tags: cart, excel

I am trying to find the best US state using 25 columns of normalized data (best = 1, worst = 0) such as crime rate, GDP, house prices, and others. This results in a 50x25 Excel table. Afterward, each state is given a score by adding the products of each variable with its respective relative weight. Here's a simplified example with trivial data:

| State | Crime rate (w = 0.2) | GDP (w = 0.3) | House prices (w = 0.5) | Mark |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Iowa | 0.20 | 1.00 | 0.15 | 42 % |
| Arkansas | 0.30 | 0.60 | 0.65 | 57 % |
| New Mexico | 0.10 | 0.40 | 0.30 | 29 % |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

This approach is functional, but working with such large amounts of data in Excel can be tedious, and maintaining the relative weight sum of 1 while staying true to my opinion becomes more challenging as more variables are added to the calculation. My goal is to gather as much data as possible to make the most objective decision subjectivity can provide. Perhaps Python could be a helpful tool? Machine learning, pandas...?

I am curious if anyone has suggestions for a better approach. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is just to keep doing the same kind of analysis but reduce the burden of updating lots of things in the table, then that can be done within Excel, although it can potentially be done even easier in a language like python or R.

In Excel, you could do something like this:

1. In one sheet, fill in all of your state data. Select all of it, and choose "Insert Table" from the menu. It will look something like this:

[image]

2. In a second sheet, create another table with the variables and their relative weights. It will also help to name the table (possibly in the Table Design menu). You'll get something that looks like this (notice that I've named the table "Weights"):

[image]

3. Back in the first table, enter the following in the Mark column (I named this table StateScores for easier reference):

`=SUMPRODUCT(StateScores[@[Crime rate]:[House prices]], TRANSPOSE(Weights[Weight])))`

Let's break down what this does:

- `StateScores[@[Crime rate]:[House prices]]` references the columns between "Crime rate" and "House prices" in the StateScores table in the current row.
- `TRANSPOSE(Weights[Weight])` references the "Weight" column in the Weights table, but since they're in column format it transposes them into a row to match the first array.
- `SUMPRODUCT` performs an element-by-element product of the two arrays and sums the results together, i.e. it calculates `Crime rate x Weight(Crime rate)` etc and then adds it all up.

If you add another variable to your table, you add another row to the Weights table and you change the reference in the above formula to cover all of the corresponding columns.

To make it even easier for you, add `/SUM(Weights[Weight])` at the end of the formula. This automatically scales everything so that the weights add to 1, meaning that you don't have to work that out yourself. You can make the weights 2, 3, 5 and they'll be adjusted appropriately.

If you were working in python or R there would be an existing function for all of this in some package, but there's an overhead involved in learning the language. And unless you're completely changing how you analyse the data, machine learning is not going to help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. I have learnt some things from it and I will be updating my file shortly!